# Double Integral with abstract functions of 2 variables

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am required to prove something, and so far I have come to set up an integral

> $$\int_0^l{\int_0^T{u(x,t)\, \frac{d}{dt}u(x,t) dt }dx}.$$

I was just wondering how to think about these integrals and approach them because they seem to be very confusing when they are not given functions. Thanks in advance! (The outer integral is an integral over the length, not from 0 to 1)

Answer (score 2):

In the inner integral we regard the function $u(x,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x,t)$ as a function in $t$. Note that the primitive with respect to $t$ is $\frac{1}{2}u(x,t)^2$. So you get
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{2}u(x,T)^2 -\frac{1}{2}u(x,0)^2dx.
$$
Now it's an integral in one variable, namely $x$ at which point you need more information about $u(x,t)$.

Comment: Would it be impossible to do anything if I had swapped the limits of integration? I started with what you had, and had to convert it to my question and somehow derive that the above integral is less than 0 (u is the standard heat equation).

Comment: It would be much harder, as the partial derivative is with respect to $t$, which makes the primitive with respect to $t$ very easy in contrast to the one with respect to $x$.

Comment: Note that if $u$ is heat then $0\leq u$, and iff the system is loosing heat then $u \left( x,t \right) <u \left( x,0 \right),\,0<t$ in which case the integrand is everywhere negative.

Comment: That logic would complete my proof, but I am not sure how to explicitly determine that the system is losing heat. The boundary conditions I am given do not include derivatives.